# Having a problem making a redundant dictionary into a function

Tags: python, function, dictionary, tuples

I am having a trouble converting a really redundant dictionary into a function (def)

The original code that works just fine is:

```
Pen = (9,'always','monday')
Paper = (1,'always','tues')
PriceDic = {'Pen': Pen[0], 
            'Paper': Paper[0]}

while True:
    name = input("name of the product?")
    print(PriceDic.get(name),'dollar')
    break
```

which prints as...

```
>>>name of the product?Pen
>>>9 dollar
```

**but** the problem is

1. I have not only Pen, and Paper but probably another 100-200 more tuples to write
2. **and** each tuple needs to contain multiple information... so the final goal of this program is to be able to fetch various info from the tuple indexes and print them.

so

I thought maybe I could function and wrote this code...

```
def FindPriceFunction(x):
    Pen = (9,'always','monday')
    Paper = (1,'always','tuesday')
    FindPriceDic = { x : x[0]}
    print(FindPriceDic.get(x),'dollar')

while True:
    name = input("name of the product?")
    FindPriceFunction(name)
    break
```

which gave me...

```
>>>name of the product?Pen
>>>P dollar
```

**PLEASE HELP ME**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the string x to access the variable name which won't work the way you're expecting, as x holds the value 'Pen', for example. This is not necessarily a recommended approach, but you can use the `locals` function to dynamically get the value of the variable like this:

```
def FindPriceFunction(x):
    Pen = (9,'always','monday')
    Paper = (1,'always','tuesday')
    print(locals()[x][0],'dollar')

while True:
    name = input("name of the product?")
    FindPriceFunction(name)
    break
```

Here, locals returns a dictionary of locally-defined variables, and you can use the string x as a key to access the value of the variable. So `locals()['Pen']` will give you the value `(9,'always','monday')`

*However*, it would be better (and safer) to just store your tuples directly into a dictionary somewhere, or maybe in a file that you read from if you don't want a long block in your code, and then access the data through there like you were originally trying, except you can store the whole tuple rather than just the price and then access the first element of the tuple for the price. `locals` returns a dictionary of the variable name as the key and the variable value as the value, so it's essentially accomplishing what you could just do in the first place with storing the value in a dict

If you wanted to store this all in a JSON file for example, since you will have hundreds of dicts, you could do this:

JSON file:

```
{
    "Pen": [9, "always", "monday"],
    "Paper": [1, "always", "tuesday"]
}
```

Code:

```
import json
with open('prices.json', 'r') as f:
    prices = json.load(f)

def FindPriceFunction(x):
    print(prices[x][0], 'dollar')
```

Comment: Hey thanks for you reply. Should I just write all the dictionary down instead of trying to reduce the redundancy? But then.. arg I just can't figure out an economical way of doing it

Comment: @JeewooLee At the end of the day, you have to store the data somewhere and get the value somehow, so I think putting all of the tuples into a dictionary is probably your best and safest best

Comment: @JeewooLee since you have a lot of data, I added a sample of how you could store it in a JSON file which is probably your easiest solution

Comment: The other comment @Thomas Kläger and yours solved my problem! huh both json file and putting tuples into a dic would be fine. Although creating a separate file would be much safer

Comment: wait may I just ask one more question? I'm sorry ahh how did you import only 9 from the [9, "always","monday"] ?

Comment: @JeewooLee sure, no problem. Are you asking about the JSON sample or the first sample using `locals`?

Comment: In either case, since `[9, "always","monday"]` is a list (or a tuple in the case of your code), I just pulled out the first element by indexing the value at position 0 of the iterable. If the variable `z` has the value `[9, "always","monday"]` then I would just do `z[0]` to get the 9

Answer (score 0):

As you gave:

```
FindPriceDic = { x : x[0]}
print(FindPriceDic.get(x),'dollar')
```

and called the function with `x as Pen`, it prints `x[0] = 'Pen'[0] = 'P'`. This caused you the problem. So try:

```
def FindPriceFunction(x):
    FindPriceDic = {}
    FindPriceDic['Pen'] = (9,'always','monday')
    FindPriceDic['Paper'] = (1,'always','tuesday')
    print(FindPriceDic.get(x)[0],'dollar')

while True:
    name = input("name of the product?")
    FindPriceFunction(name)
    break
```

Comment: I've simplified a bit?

Answer (score 0):

You could write your data as a dictionary from the beginning (the values in a dictionary can be any type, a tuple is fine):

```
my_data = {
    'Pen': (9, 'always', 'monday'),
    'Paper': (1, 'always', 'tuesday')
}

def FindPriceFunction(x):
    print(my_data.get(x)[0],'dollar')

while True:
    name = input("name of the product?")
    FindPriceFunction(name)
    break
```

Comment: OMG this solves my problem! Thank you so much! I didn't know that I can store values in a dic as a tuple! This is perfect thank you genius! 

Answer (score 0):

In case you would need to be more flexible with your data structure, you can also rely on semantic keys, rather than operate with indexes of tuples.

#### products.yaml

```yaml
Pen:
  price: 9
  frequency: Always
  day: Monday
Paper:
  price: 1
  frequency: Rarely
  day: Tuesday
Scissors:
  frequency: Often
```

#### main.py

```py
import yaml  # pyyaml package

with open("products.yaml", 'r') as stream:
    try:
        products = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
        print(exc)
print(products)
print(products['Pen']['price'])


def find_price(product_name):
    try:
        return products[product_name]['price']
    except KeyError:
        return "N/A"


print(find_price('Pen'))
print(find_price('Scissors'))
```